# La base de datos de postgresql 14 se borra solita luego 3 horas aproximadamente de su creación(VPS)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, vps, digitalocean

Tengo una api implementada con java-spring y postgresql. He comprado un vps con SO ubunto, se ha instalado java y postgresql 14( la instalación y creación de la base de datos lo he hecho como si estuviera en una máquina local) en el vps. En el aplicaction.properties tengo el siguiente código:

```
server.port=8090
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.199:5432/db_psicodidact

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123

#HTTPS


#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
spring.jackson.time-zone =America/Santiago
```

El api se comunica correctamente con la base de datos, puedo hacer varias peticiones sin problemas, pero al pasar unas horas, me sale un error que la base de datos no existe, se ha borrado de manera mágica. llevo varios días con ese problema y  no encuentro el error. Por favor su ayuda para lograr estabilizar mi api en el VPS. Adicional tengo un demonio de java para que mi api este activo 24/7.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No tendrias que preguntar a quien te da el VPS?? si algo se borra solo, nos va a costar darte una idea.. si se borra, es porque alguien lo borra...

Comment: En la configuración no veo nada raro, si tienes un problema debe estar o en la propia base de datos o puede que sea algo que haces en el código, es imposible saberlo con la poca información que das.

Comment: es raro lo que comentas, quizas alguien externo?
la opcion spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate?

Answer (score 0):

Solucione cambiando el archivo properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.